# How redirect a page with htaccess and relative requests?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to type on browser

```
    mydomain.me/myproject
```

instead to type

```
    mydomain.me/fold1/fold2/yymmdd-myproject
```

It works after I've added the code below in .htaccess:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^myproject/?$ fold1/fold2/yymmdd-myproject/ [NC,L]
```

But now the requests from the index page (css, script sources...) call them from the domain's root (mydomain.me, not from mydomain.me/myproject/) and, of course, the server responds with "not found".

How can I fix it?

**UPDATE 1**

I tried to write this (just added the domain in path):

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^myproject/?$ http://mydomain.me/fold1/fold2/yymmdd-myproject/ [NC,L]
```

and now the page loads correctly with css and other libraries, but the url in address bar is *mydomain.me/fold1/fold2/yymmdd-myproject/* instead like *mydomain.me/myproject* as I read in Apache document.

Comment: What does your css/js links look like?

Comment: as an usual index page:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" >
<script src="framework/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

Comment: And what is correct path of your css/js files? Do you have more rules as well?

Comment: I had written above. There aren't more rules in .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved in this way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^myproject$ http://mydomain.me/myproject/ [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^myproject/(.+)?$ fold1/fold2/yymmdd-myproject/$1 [NC,L]
```

Two lines per project.